# Excel 2016 Array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula in excel (created by me in the past),

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Tasks!$H$2:$H$65536;SMALL(IF(A2=Tasks!$A$2:$A$65536;ROW(Tasks!$A$2:$A$65536)-ROW(Tasks!$A$2)+1);ROW($1:$1)));"")
```

The formula is working as I wanted, but in each and every month the a columns are changing, so for example what was Column "A" here can be Column "C" next month and so the number of rows are changing. I'm trying to modify the formula that I don't have to adjust month by month.

For this first I found a VBA script online:

```
  Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
        Dim vArr
        vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
        Col_Letter = vArr(0)
    End Function
```

So after if I type for example:
`=Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table8[[#Headers];[ID]]))` it will give me Letter "B" as this header can be found in "B" Column.

So using the advantage of this VBA script I was trying to create a formula what will adjust the column letter in the original formula every time.

So this formula:

```
=("Tasks!" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[Owned By]])) & "$" & "2" & ":" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[Owned By]])) & "$" & ROW(INDEX(Table32;1;1))+ROWS(Table32)-1) is giving me this as the result Tasks!$H$2:$H$65536.
```

what is part of the formula so I think it's good.

This is the whole formula I was trying to re-create in this manner:

```
=Index((("Tasks!" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[Owned By]])) & "$" & ROW() & ":" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[Owned By]])) & "$" & ROW(INDEX(Table32;1;1))+ROWS(Table32)-1);SMALL(IF((((Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table8[[#Headers];[ID]])) & ROW()) & "=" & (("Tasks!" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[ID]])) & "$" & "2"& ":" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[ID]])) & "$" & ROW(INDEX(Table32;1;1))+ROWS(Table32)-1))));Row((("Tasks!" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[ID]])) & "$" & "2"& ":" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[ID]])) & "$" & ROW(INDEX(Table32;1;1))+ROWS(Table32)-1)))-ROW(("Tasks!" & "$" & Col_Letter(COLUMN(Table32[[#Headers];[ID]])) & "$" & "2"))+1);ROWS($1:$1))))
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the formula? Do you get an error? Does it return something other than what's expected?

Comment: I have added the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel **Tables** have the potential of resolving such questions easily. Since the Columns can be referred by their names, you do not have to worry where they are located. And likewise, since you reference the data by column name but not row number, your reference will be covering all of the rows within that Table, no matter how many rows are added or deleted.

So as a start, try converting your range to Table by selecting it and use **Insert** / **Table**. After this you should convert your formula to contain Table references rather than cell references.